# VBA: Programming Stand-Alone Version of Goalseek Macro Equivalent

Tags: vba, porting

I have an Excel Macro in VBA using goalseek. I want to convert this macro into a stand alone VBA file in order to insert in another vba program. Is there an equivalent to goalseek in VBA that I can use?

Comment: I asume, this other vba program is not an Excel vba program. Otherwise you could just use the same reference to goalseek...

Comment: What is "the other VBA program"? Another Excel workbook?

Comment: I'm actually writing a VBA extension for ASPEN HYSYS

Comment: While my excel macro uses VBA, I'm actually going to try to export my code as VB to be used be another program

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to continue referencing Excel you'll have to write your own implementation of GoalSeek.